# Additive order of $1$ in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a (unital) ring. 
I have met in various places the expression "*the additive order of $1$ in $R$*". As far as I can understand, this is another expression for "*the characteristic of the ring $R$*".

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is the order of $1$ as an element of the additive group of the ring. This is almost the same thing as the characteristic, except that if the additive order of $1$ is infinite, then one says the ring has characteristic $0$ (not infinity).